# What's the difference between these two connected apps?

Tags: connected-apps

I've included a connected app in a managed package, but the one on the packaging org looks different to the one on a target developer org after I've installed the package.

On the packaging org I find the connected app on the Apps page and can view it to find the consumer key and secret.

[image]

After installing the package on the target org, there is no entry on that Apps page.

[image]

There is one however on the Connected Apps page of the target org

[image]

But when I view this one there are no entries for the consumer key and secret.

What has happened here? What has changed during packaging / installation.
What's the relationship between the different views of the connected apps?

Answer (score 2):

The client id/secret is a feature for the packaging org to implement their app. Subscribers that install the package won't see this information, because it's not meant for them. The only reason they see the package at all is so they can configure permissions/block the app from user profiles. Just like you wouldn't give your username and password to your subscribers, nor would you give them the client id/secret, since it would allow them to masquerade as your application.